# Iterations for the numpy arrays for following problem

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop

i have 3 numpy arrays a,c and m, i want a loop which takes every element from a,c,m in each loop. For example in first iteration it takes `4,3,6` and executes `z=(a*2+c)%m` five times then in second it takes `5,5,5` and execute same expression 5 times. i want random number generation. see code below

```
a = [[4, 5, 1], [4, 3, 1], [6, 7, 2]]

c = [[3, 5, 1], [4, 3, 1], [6, 7, 2]]

m = [[6, 5, 1], [4, 3, 1], [6, 7, 2]]

for i in range(0, 5):
    z = (a * 2 + c) % m
```

Comment: Why would you want to loop over a numpy array? Isn't a goal of numpy to prevent you from manually looping? What are you trying to do?

Comment: Seems to be an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the reason why you want to extract the elements from those matrix, this is a simple solution :

```
for i in range(a.shape[1]):
  for j in range(b.shape[0]):
    print([a[i,j], b[i,j], c[i,j]])
```

If you are interested in doing advanced operations with them like matrix multiplication,..., I recommend you to use the slice techniques  offerd by Numpy.

Answer (score 0):

```
for i, j, k in zip(a, c, m):
    for l, n, o in zip(i, j, k):
        for i in range(0,5)
            z=(a*2+c)%m
```

Answer (score 0):

```
it = np.nditer(a, flags=['multi_index'])
for x in it:
  print("%d%d%d "%(a[it.multi_index],c[it.multi_index],m[it.multi_index]))
```

Comment: `it = np.nditer(a, flags=['multi_index'])
for x in it:
    a=a[it.multi_index]
    c=c[it.multi_index]
    m=m[it.multi_index]`

Comment: I want something like this but it gives error

Comment: it will work if you will use different variable names, i.e.
it = np.nditer(a, flags=['multi_index']) 
for x in it:
     a_elem=a[it.multi_index]
     c_elem=c[it.multi_index]
     m_elem=m[it.multi_index]

Comment: I don't encourage the use of `nditer`.  In the `c` version it is useful, but the python interface is slow and hard to use correctly.